# Zeppelin with Spark 1.5.1 Standalone cluster fails

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am running the following:
- spark standalone cluster (pre-build: http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz)
- Zeppelin 0.5.0 (tag: https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/releases/tag/v0.5.0)
- Oracle JDK 8u66

I am able to start a spark shell from any of the spark cluster machines.

I have installed Zeppelin as follow (https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/install/install.html):

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin zeppelin
cd zeppelin
git checkout tags/v0.5.0
mvn install -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.5.1 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0
```

I have configured `zeppelin-env.sh` as follow:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/home/spark/java"
export MASTER="spark://master:7077"
export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=2g -Dspark.cores.max=8"
export ZEPPELIN_MEM="-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
export SPARK_HOME=/home/spark/spark
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/home/spark/spark/conf
```

Note that SPARK_HOME is the same spark version than the one available on the nodes of the spark cluster.

Now I create my first note and to test the connection to the cluster I ran:

```
%spark val ctx = new org.apache.spark.sql.SqlContext(sc)
```

and I get the following errors

```
ERROR [2015-11-09 12:02:40,172] ({pool-1-thread-3} ProcessFunction.java[process]:41) - Internal error processing getProgress
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: akka.ConfigurationException: Akka JAR version [2.3.11] does not match the provided config version [2.3.4]
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.open(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:68)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getProgress(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:109)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.getProgress(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:938)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:923)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: Akka JAR version [2.3.11] does not match the provided config version [2.3.4]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:210)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:505)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1913)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1904)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:450)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:301)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:423)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.open(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:73)
    ... 11 more
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In version 1.5.(1) Spark uses 2.3.11 version of akka.

Zeppelin version 0.5 doesn't have any changes related to that.

If it is possible - it is better to use 0.5.5 version (released 4 days ago), as there is already a spark-1.5 profile with all of the needed dependencies:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/blob/v0.5.5/spark-dependencies/pom.xml#L459

Also, using spark profile in Zeppelin (rather than spark.version property) will automatically set everything else to correct version.

```
mvn clean install -Pspark-1.5 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Phadoop-2.6 -DskipTests
```

---

Update 1:

It seems that v0.5.5 relies on the SNAPSHOT version of the apache-jar-resource-bundle. Due to such changes, the apache snapshot repository should also be added to maven settings (.m2/settings.xml):

```xml
  <profiles>
    <profile>
    ...
      <repositories>
    ...
        <repository>
          <id>apache-snapshots</id>
          <name>apache-snapshots</name>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    ...
      </repositories>
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot or this answer, I have just tried this but I it appears this release of Zeppelin does try to download a remote resource bundle (org.apache.apache.resources:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.5-SNAPSHOT) in the root POM which fails the build ... 



rely on SNAPSHOT artifact that cannot be resolved in public repos: org.apache.apache.resources:apache-jar-resource-bundle:jar:1.5-SNAPSHOT, 1.4 appears to be the latest available (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache/apache-jar-resource-bundle). This is what pushed me to use tag 0.5.0 in the first place.

Comment: It also appears the zeppelin/phoenix/pom.xml transitively needs sqlline:sqlline:1.1.8 which isn't found in public repos, I have added sqlline:sqlline:1.1.9 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/sqlline/sqlline/1.1.9) which seem to have fixed the build issue.

Comment: Regarding the **apache-jar-resource-bundle** - it can be fixed by adding http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/ to maven settings.xml.

Comment: Updated the answer with the snapshot repository details.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer rchukh ! Looks to me like  Zeppelin should have this declared in the root pom so save people having to their local settings ...

Comment: Then the zeppelin-web fails witht he following message "Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:grunt (grunt build) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'grunt --no-color' failed. (error code 3)" this is a reported issue on Zeppelin's JIRA https://goo.gl/NTt1e5 and there is a dirty fix available.